# NHibernate generates INSERT and UPDATE for new entity

Tags: nhibernate

I have an entity with Id column generated using Hilo.
I have a transaction, creating a new entity and calling SaveOrUpdate() in order to get the Hilo generated Id of the entity (I need to write that Id to another DB).

later on, within the same transaction I update the new entity, just a simple update of a simple property, and in the end I call SaveOrUpdate() again.

I see that the SQL commands generated are first INSERT and then an UPDATE, but what I want is just an INSERT with the final details of the entity. is that possible? am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT: added code sample**

here's a very simplified example of pseudo code:

```
Person newPerson = new Person(); // Person is a mapped entity
newPerson.Name = "foo";
_session.SaveOrUpdate(newPerson); // generates INSERT statement

newPerson.BirthDate = DateTime.Now;
_session.SaveOrUpdate(newPerson); // generates UPDATE statement

// assume session transaction was opened before and disposed correctly for sake of simplicity
_session.Transaction.Commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

The point is that with ORM tools like NHibernate, we are working different way, then we did with *ADO.NET*.

While ADO.NET `Commands` and their `Execute()` method family would cause immediate SQL statement execution on the DB server... with NHibernate it is dramatically different.

We are working with a `ISession`. The session, could be thought as a C# collection in a memory. All the `Save()`, `SaveOrUdpate()`, `Update()`, `Delete()` ... calls are executed against that object representation. NO SQL Command is executed, when calling these methods, no *low-level* ADO.NET calls at the moment.

That *abstraction* allows NHibernate to optimize the final SQL Statement batch... based on all the information gathered in the `ISession`. And that's why, you will never see INSERT, UPDATE if working with one `Session`, unless we explictly call the magical `Flush()` or change the FlushMode at all.

In that case *(calling* `Flush()` *)*, we are trying to say: NHibernate we are smart enough, now is the time to execute commands. In other scenarios, usually it is good enough to leave it on NHibernate...

See here: 
- [9.6. Flush](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-flushing)

Comment: I understand the mechanics of Flush(), I just expected an optimized behavior where an entity is inserted and then updated in the same session, only a single INSERT statement would be generated with the final values of the entity.

Comment: That all depends on the mapping you have in place. If NHibernate can do that in a single insert, it will be in most cases done this way. But honestly... if you are in a transaction and in one session... the Save() is enough to be called. Because then, until you are working with the transient objects, all the changes are still applied into that "unsaved" object. The fulsh will save the final version. If there is an explicit call to insert.. it could mean, that some other dependencies forces that action (relationship) etc.